# Not able to parse HTMLCollection list

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape out some links from a site using javascript. In the below HTML I have some links in the 'a' tag. And I am using the following JS.

The problem is that I am not able to get the links from the myChildList.

When I console.log myDownloadDiv, it shows me the output as object HTMLElement. When I console.log the myChildList (i.e the children of the HTMLElement) I get something like a HTMLCollection [a.dropdown-item.disabled] in which the length is 2 and with both the anchor tags  and with all their properties in it with the links.

When I want to console.log all the elements using a loop, it shows only one element and the output is like this:

```
<a class="dropdown-item disabled"></a>
```

I don't understand if I am doing something wrong while parsing out the HTMLCollection List.

```js
var myDownloadDiv = document.getElementById("pickDownload");
var myChildList = myDownloadDiv.children;
console.log(myChildList);

for (var j of myChildList) {
  console.log(j);
}
```

```html
<div class="col-12 col-sm-3">
  <div class="dropup">
    <a href="" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block dropdown-toggle" id="downloadMenu" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Download
            </a>

    <div class="dropdown-menu" id="pickDownload" aria-labelledby="downloadMenu">
      <a href="https://fainbory.com/4eQM" class="dropdown-item" target="_blank">
        <span class="badge badge-primary">BD</span> Elysium - 720p (129 MB)
      </a>
      <a href="https://fainbory.com/4eQP" class="dropdown-item" target="_blank">
        <span class="badge badge-primary">BD</span> Elysium - 1080p (239 MB)
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

I tried the solutions. They work perfectly in the snippets but they are not working on the [site](https://animepahe.com/play/96afc1bc-52d2-9679-cce3-58517c495cab/07c1327119e6006a35f16bd47150b91bb6ddbcfeaea2bcce87054931b08e2036) which I am trying to scrape.

Comment: I tried your code with `snippet` option and I got 2 elemented logged in the console.

Comment: @TalRofe The dropdown menu is hidden by default. Can that make a difference?

Comment: If you mean `hidden` with CSS, then CSS should not influence this `console.log` results.

Comment: I made you a snippet. It seems to run as expected

Comment: This is the link to the site that I am trying to scrape. 
https://animepahe.com/play/96afc1bc-52d2-9679-cce3-58517c495cab/07c1327119e6006a35f16bd47150b91bb6ddbcfeaea2bcce87054931b08e2036

I also don't understand why the snippet is not working on the site.

Comment: Even when running your code with inspect mode (typically via `F12` key): When running your code in console tab, I do get 2 `<a>` elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop seems to work.

Perhaps you meant this

```js
const links = [...document.querySelectorAll("#pickDownload a")].map(link => link.href);
console.log(links);
```

```html
<div class="col-12 col-sm-3">
  <div class="dropup">
    <a href="" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block dropdown-toggle" id="downloadMenu" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Download
            </a>

    <div class="dropdown-menu" id="pickDownload" aria-labelledby="downloadMenu">
      <a href="https://fainbory.com/4eQM" class="dropdown-item" target="_blank">
        <span class="badge badge-primary">BD</span> Elysium - 720p (129 MB)
      </a>
      <a href="https://fainbory.com/4eQP" class="dropdown-item" target="_blank">
        <span class="badge badge-primary">BD</span> Elysium - 1080p (239 MB)
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a bookmarklet

```
javascript:(function() { const links = [...document.querySelectorAll("#pickDownload a")].map(link => link.href); console.log(links))()
```

Comment: The snippet is working perfectly but it's not working on the site in question. Please check the following link: 
https://animepahe.com/play/96afc1bc-52d2-9679-cce3-58517c495cab/07c1327119e6006a35f16bd47150b91bb6ddbcfeaea2bcce87054931b08e2036

Comment: Works for me when I run in the console

Comment: Here is a bookmarklet `javascript:(function() { const links = [...document.querySelectorAll("#pickDownload a")].map(link => link.href); console.log(links))()`

Comment: Ok, So I tried the solutions and it worked perfectly fine when I downloaded the whole page and added the JS in a script tag in the HTML file. Thanks
I was using Tampermonkey ext. earlier to run JS code on the site. Though I still don't know why doesn't Tampermonkey works when I try to do so.

Comment: Maybe the tampermonkey script runs before the page has finished loading?

Comment: Yup. That's what was the problem. I solved it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

your code is correct and works properly on my machine, I think there's an issue with your console object.

Please try to remove this import https://static.lalaping.com/online.js?ver=2.0.0:formatted
I suspect the console object is overwritten there.

You can verify this on you site, just running in the browser console the following commands:

```
// Restore console object:
var i = document.createElement('iframe');
i.style.display = 'none';
document.body.appendChild(i);
window.console = i.contentWindow.console;

// Run your code:
var myDownloadDiv = document.getElementById("pickDownload");
var myChildList = myDownloadDiv.children;
console.log(myChildList);

for (var j of myChildList) {
  console.log(j);
}
```

Comment: It is not his page. And the Bookmarklet I wrote works just fine